# rvest + selector gadget return empty list

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm attempting to scrape political endorsement data from wikipedia tables (a pretty generic scraping task) and the regular process of using `rvest` on the css path identified by selector gadget is failing.

The wiki page is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endorsements_for_the_Republican_Party_presidential_primaries,_2012), and the css path `.jquery-tablesorter:nth-child(11) td` seems to select the right part of the page [image: right part of wikitable selected]

Armed with the css, I would normally just use `rvest` to directly access these data, as follows:

```
"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endorsements_for_the_Republican_Party_presidential_primaries,_2012" %>% 
   html %>% 
   html_nodes(".jquery-tablesorter:nth-child(11) td")
```

but this returns:

```
list()
attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLNodeSet"
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: What part of the page are you actually trying trying to get?

Comment: The table, from the "Former President" column to "Notes"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help:

```
library(rvest)
URL <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endorsements_for_the_Republican_Party_presidential_primaries,_2012" 
tab <- URL %>% read_html %>%  
            html_node("table.wikitable:nth-child(11)") %>% html_table()
```

This code stores the table that you requested as a dataframe in the variable `tab`.

```
> View(tab)
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks!

I wonder..how did you know to change the CSS call?

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad I could help. I just study the structure of the webpage with the "inspector" option of the firefox browser. It's often a trial and error approach.

Answer (score 1):

I find that if I use the xpath suggestion from Chrome it works.

Chrome suggests an xpath of `//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[4]`

I can then run as follows

```
library(rvest)

    URL <-"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endorsements_for_the_Republican_Party_presidential_primaries,_2012" 
    tab <- URL %>% 
      read_html %>%  
      html_node(xpath='//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[4]') %>% 
      html_table()
```

Comment: I know this was a long time ago but I am having a similar issue with distinguishing the correct css tags, how did you get the xpath suggestion from Chrome instead? I've had a look in the DevTools window but I can't find it!

Comment: If you look at the html under the "Elements" tab and right click the element you want the path for, then follow Copy>>Copy XPath